# How to align image and advertisement side by side using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

HTML code:

```
<div class="goleft"> AD 300x250 size </div>


        <div class="itemImageBlock goleft">
              <span class="itemImage">
              <img src="/media/k2/items/cache/c3997142576e6f4d163ead570965368d_S.jpg" alt="Pranab Mukherjee" style="width:300px; height:250px;" />
          </span>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.itemImageBlock { margin:0 0 16px; padding:0; text-align: center; clear: both; }
span.itemImage { display:block; text-align:center; margin:0 0 8px 0; }
.goleft{
    float:left
}
```

these 2 blocks are coming one after other. i want these to align side by side.

Please help me in achieving this.

If i change the order of the div blocks(first image next ad) its working. but i want first ad and next image.

image URL: http://tinypic.com/r/2ih5hco/6

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The PHP isn't relevant here. Post your generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an extra class to your css code to make it clutter free...

CSS

```
.goleft{
    float:left
}
```

and add this class to your DOM -

```
       <div class="itemImageBlock goleft">
              <span class="itemImage">

              </span>
         </div>
         <!-- Advertisement(300x250) -->
          <div class = "goleft">
          </div>
```

Comment: But how i can crop the image to 300x250?  can you help me please.

Comment: i got cropping but , image and ad are not aligning side by side

Comment: if i go with order like image and ad its working, but if i place ad block first its not working.

Comment: You should probably post a screen of what you have and what you want it to look like

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be in the `.itemImageBlock` CSS declaration. Remove the `clear:both` CSS and the DIVs will align. See: http://jsfiddle.net/pe6s5/

Comment: yes perfect(Thank you)..now they are aligned side by side. can i know how to get space between these 2 div blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.itemImageBlock {padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
span.itemImage {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0 8px 0;
}
.goleft{
    float:left;
}
```

and

```
<div class="goleft"> AD 300x250 size </div>
<div class="itemImageBlock">
    <span class="itemImage">
        <img src="/media/k2/items/cache/c3997142576e6f4d163ead570965368d_S.jpg" alt="Pranab Mukherjee" style="width:300px; height:250px;" />
    </span>
</div>
```